# Run an R script at boot

Tags: r, ubuntu, redis, multicore, autostart

First of all, this may need to be moved to superuser.  I couldn't decide which venue was better.

I am trying to write an R script that will run at boot/reboot and add that machine to a pool of [doRedis](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doRedis/index.html) workers. (doRedis is a [foreach](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/index.html) backend).

Here is my R script, "~/Rworker.R"

```
#Define Parameters
require(multicore)
Host <- 'ip_of_doRedis_Server'
cores <- multicore:::detectCores()
TO <- 24*3600

#Start Workers
require('doRedis')
startLocalWorkers(cores,'jobs',host=Host,port=6379, timeout = TO)
```

I can run this script from the command line, using the command
`sudo R CMD BATCH ~/Rworker.R ~/RLog`.

Next, I wrote a shell script to run the R script, titled "/etc/init.d/StartWorkers.sh"

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo echo "Starting R workers"
sudo R CMD BATCH ~/Rworker.R ~/RLog
```

I made this shell script executable, using `chmod +x StartWorkers.sh`.  When I run `./StartWorkers.sh` everything works great and the R session starts up and the workers get added to the pool.

Now, I need this shell script to run when I boot/reboot the machine, so I type
`update-rc.d StartWorkers.sh defaults`.  This command appears to work, but I get the following warning:
'update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/StartWorkers.sh missing LSB information'

However, a check with rcconf confirms that "StartWorkers.R" is on the startuplist.

However, when I reboot the machine, the script fails to run. What am I doing wrong? The shell script runs fine from the command line, but fails when I try to run it at startup.

/EDIT: ok, per Dirk's answer, I installed littler, and changed 'StartWorkers.sh' to the following:

```
#! /usr/bin/r

#Define Parameters
require(multicore)
Host <- 'zachec2.dyndns.org'
cores <- multicore:::detectCores()
TO <- 24*3600

#Start Workers
require('doRedis')
startLocalWorkers(cores,'jobs',host=Host,port=6379, timeout = TO)
```

But when I run it, I get the following output:

```
Loading required package: utils
Loading required package: multicore
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'multicore'
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'multicore'
Calls: ::: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

I know I have multicore installed on my system!

/EDIT2: I had to move all my R packages to `cd /usr/lib/R/site-library` and now the littler shell script works.  I added the script to `/etc/rc.local` and it starts up perfectly!

Comment: I'd say Superuser would in fact be better for this.

Comment: Add a `print(.libPaths())`.  Maybe you have multicore in *your* `~/R/library` which `root` does not see. One remedy: `apt-get install r-cran-multicore`.

Comment: When I add that line, I get the following result before the error `[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"            "/usr/lib64/R/library"`

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel: I ran `apt-get install r-cran-multicore`, but now littler can't find the `doRedis` package, and unfortunately `apt-get install r-cran-doRedis`doesn't work

Comment: I install all my local packages in `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`; that way all users find them.  If you packages are scattered over your system, add location options to the `library()` call.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel: This may be a dumb question, but how do I figure out where R has been installing my packages?  It turns out it's not any of the 4 directories I listed earlier, which explains my problem...

Comment: Maybe `locate doRedis` can help.

Comment: @Zach fire up R and look at the output of `.libPaths()` it will till you where R will look for it's packages.

Comment: @Dirk: I ran .libPaths() from an interactive R session and figured it out.  Thank you.

Comment: Please do **not use `/usr/lib/R/site-library`** by hand, use `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`. The **`local`** matters.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel: Pardon my ignorance, but what's the difference between the 2 libraries?  When I installed multicore using apt-get, ut sent it to `/usr/lib/R/site-library` so I assumed that's where packages needed to be for littler to find them.

Comment: The package management system owns `/usr` and below; you as admin own `usr/local`. They are separate for a reason, and your sanity will be greater if you do not mix them.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel: I've already mixed them, by copying all my packages from `/usr/local/lib64/R/library` to `/usr/lib/R/site-library`.  Should I move all of them (except multicore, which was previously there) to `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`?

Comment: Here is what I would do:  Find the ones which `dpkg` or `apt` installed into `/usr/lib/R/site-library` an leave them. The others you installed, move them to `/usr/local/....`

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel. Done.  Thanks for the warning!

Comment: Hi! I am having the same issue you had and cant seem to get it working. When you said you added the script to /etc/rc.local you added a link to your script like ./etc/yourscript.sh or you added your code inside rc.local? Thanks a lot for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bit of an R question, and a bit on an Ubuntu sysadmining question. here are a few points:

1. For simple start-up tasks, I recommned just using `/etc/rc.local` where you can append you jobs.
2. I just don't like `R CMD BATCH` which is why Jeff Horner and I wrote [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) which gives you `/usr/bin/r` and much easier R scripting.  R itself also gives you `Rscript`; either one is preferable over `R CMD BATCH`.
3. To test scripts, just run them as root. Once theyw ork, add them to `/etc/rc.local`.

Hope this helps. The `r-sig-debian` list is a good source of Ubuntu / Debian tips too.

Comment: I have never heard of Rscript.  How does that works?  And I agree... I hate R CMD BATCH with a passion.

Comment: Rscript is provided by R Core and in your Ubuntu binaries as /usr/bin/Rscript so see its documentation.  Our /usr/bin/r (which you can `apt-get install littler`) came out just before Rscript and is yet a little lighter and faster. Play with either and you'd be happy.

Comment: I got the littler script to work and added the following line to `/etc/rc.local`: `sudo /etc/init.d/StartWorkers.sh`.  However, the script still appears to not be running when I boot

Comment: Oh boy. First, no need for sudo as `/etc/rc.local` is executed by root itself.  Second, I suggested `/etc/rc.local` *instead of* going through `/etc/init.d/`. Third, if it breaks you get to keep the pieces and debug yourself.  There is nothing we can do from here given the info your provided. Sorry.

Comment: I removed the sudo, removed the script from `/etc/init.d/` and ran it solely through `/etc/rc.local`, and it's now working perfectly.  Thank you so much for all of your help, I'm very happy to discover littler.

Comment: Cool!  Good to see your persistence paid off.  These are nitty little details but now that you mastered this you can automate the hell out of it.

Comment: I appreciate your patience.  Thank you!