# Why (or when) is Rscript (or littler) better than R CMD BATCH?

Tags: r, batch-file, cmd, cron, rscript

I am automating some webscraping with `R` in `cron` and sometimes I use `R CMD BATCH` and sometimes I use `Rscript`.

To decide which one to use I mainly focus if I want the `.Rout` file or not.

But reading the answers to some questions here in SO (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390913/run-an-r-script-at-boot/6391030#6391030) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167178/passing-command-line-arguments-to-r-cmd-batch)) it seems that `Rscript` is preferred to `R CMD BATCH`.

So my questions are:

- Besides the fact that the syntax is a little different and `R CMD BATCH` saves an `.Rout` file while `Rscript` does not, what are the main differences between the two of them?
- When should I prefer one over another? More specifically, in the `cron` job above mentioned, is one of them preferred?
- I have not used yet `littler`, how is it different from both `Rscript` and `R CMD BATCH`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`R CMD BATCH` is all we had years ago. It makes i/o very hard and leaves files behind.

Things got better, first with littler and then too with Rscript.  Both can be used for 'shebang' lines such as

```
 #!/usr/bin/r

 #!/usr/bin/Rscript
```

and both can be used with packages like getopt and optparse --- allowing you to write proper R scripts that can act as commands.  If have dozens of them, starting with simple ones like this which I can call as `install.r pkga pkgb pkgc` and which will install all three and their dependencies) for me from the command-line without hogging the R prompt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env r       
#
# a simple example to install one or more packages 

if (is.null(argv) | length(argv)<1) {
  cat("Usage: installr.r pkg1 [pkg2 pkg3 ...]\n")
  q()
}

## adjust as necessary, see help('download.packages') 
repos <- "http://cran.rstudio.com"

## this makes sense on Debian where no packages touch /usr/local 
lib.loc <- "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"

install.packages(argv, lib.loc, repos)
```

And just like Karl, I have cronjobs calling similar R scripts.

*Edit on 2015-11-04:*  As of last week, [littler is now also on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/littler/index.html).

Answer (score 41):

From what I understand:

**R CMD BATCH:**

- echo the input statements
- can not output to stdout

**Rscript:**

- does NOT echo
- output to stdout
- can be used in one-liner (i.e. with no input file)

**littler:**

- all that Rscript does
- can read commands from stdin (useful for pipelining)
- faster startup time
- load the methods package

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel You are correct. Pairing somewhere in the docs `commandArgs` to `argv` would make it better for searching. BTW. why not to modify `commandArgs()` at littler init to make it a more portable and support code which was written having `Rscript` in mind? just filled FR.

Comment: So can we/shall we delete these four or five comments?  They are just noise.

Comment: Re your last con:  [littler is now a CRAN package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/littler/index.html) too.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel fixed.