# R phangorn Rscript R CMD BATCH different results

Tags: r

I'm receiving strange error when trying to run an `R` script using the `phangorn` package. Whenever I run the script using: 
`Rscript mini_example.R`
It fails with the error message:

```
Error in as.vector(data) : 
no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
Calls: pml ... as.matrix -> as.matrix.default -> array -> as.vector
```

Which could suggest some Namespace troubles. However when running `R CMD BATCH mini_example.R OUT.txt` everything runs smooth, no errors.

Code `mini_example.R`:

```
library(phangorn)
sessionInfo()
data(Laurasiatherian)
dm <- dist.ml(Laurasiatherian)
tree <- NJ(dm)
fitJC <- pml(tree, Laurasiatherian)  
fitJC <- optim.pml(fitJC)
print('==>>Success <<==')
```

I've compared the `sessionInfo()` for both the `Rscript` and the `R CMD BATCH` (see below) and the only difference is that methods is not attached when using `Rscript` but loaded via Namespace. I'm a bit confused about this behavior, so it would be great if someone with more knowledge might have an idea what might cause the `Rscript` trouble...

For R CMD BATCH

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] phangorn_1.99.14 ape_3.3         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Matrix_1.2-2    nnls_1.4        parallel_3.2.1  igraph_0.7.1   
[5] nlme_3.1-120    grid_3.2.1      lattice_0.20-31 quadprog_1.5-5
```

For Rscript

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  base     

other attached packages:
[1] phangorn_1.99.14 ape_3.3         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Matrix_1.2-2    nnls_1.4        parallel_3.2.1  igraph_0.7.1   
[5] nlme_3.1-120    grid_3.2.1      methods_3.2.1   lattice_0.20-31
[9] quadprog_1.5-5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with `Rscript` if you import `library(methods)` in addition to `phangorn`. This changes the sessionInfo() for `methods` from "loaded via a namespace (and not attached)" to "attached base packages", which was the only difference between your sessionInfo() for `Rscript` vs `R CMD BATCH`.

I don't know why the two would differ. However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969145/why-or-when-is-rscript-or-littler-better-than-r-cmd-batch#answer-22355386) remarks that [`littler`](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) (an alternative to `Rscript`) "load the methods package", which would suggest that the authors of `littler` have experienced your issue too.

Comment: Your solution works. Citing from `?Rscript`: Rscript omits methods as it takes about 60% of the startup time... So that's the reason, wasn't aware of that.