# SAS program equivalent in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I'm wondering if R has something similar to SAS program where it can store the codes? I need to run the analysis on my data set (update monthly) every month. In SAS, I can just run the program and it will give me the results. I'd like to know if R has something similar to that? Thank you so much!

[Update] Thanks for the answers. R script is what I'm looking for!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - just store your code in a text file and then `source()` it when necessary. SAS files are just plain text too, so i'm not sure what difference it makes. Oh, and this isn't the place for such questions - Stackoverflow is for specific programming questions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That solved my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just talking about running an R script?? If you have a text file called `codefile.R` containing R code, then from within an interactive R session `source("codefile.R")` will run it.  Or you can use `R CMD BATCH codefile.R` from a command line/shell/terminal.

**update**: Dirk Eddelbuettel points out that `Rscript` or the [littler package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/littler/index.html) [are recommended over R CMD BATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969145/why-or-when-is-rscript-or-littler-better-than-r-cmd-batch) ...

Comment: Boooo. Don't promote `R CMD BATCH`.  We've had `Rscript` for almost a decade, ie almost as long as littler, and it is vastly superior.

Comment: you can edit the question if you like ... (I am so backward that I'm still confused by the difference between `Rscript -e`, `echo {text} | R --slave`, and `r` ...)

Comment: Feel free to search on SO for that then :)   The question has been addressed a few times.

Comment: still haven't found the information for `Rscript -e` vs `echo ... | R --slave` -- I know there's something about which packages/environment stuff get loaded by default. If I find time maybe I'll try to write a SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just like you can create SAS programs in the enhanced editor, you can create [R scripts](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Lemon-kickstart/kr_scrpt.html) in R.  This process is even easier, in my opinion, when you write your R scripts using the tools that come with [R Studio](https://www.rstudio.com).