# change the location of the .file generate by sbatch job.sh

Tags: slurm

When I make the command *sbatch job.sh* and everything runs smoothly, a file test.Rout is generated at the location of my job.sh, I would like to know how to change the location of this .Rout file.

**job.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name="test
#SBATCH --nodes=1                # number of nodes
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=10      # number of cores
#SBATCH --time=01:00:00          # walltime
#SBATCH --output=error/job.out
#SBATCH --error=error/error.err

module load R

R CMD BATCH test.R
```

**test.R**

```
print(2+2)
```

**test.Rout**

```
R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[Previously saved workspace restored]

> print(2+2)
[1] 4
>
> proc.time()
   user  system elapsed
  0.107   0.039   0.154
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the `test.Rout` file is not generated by the `job.sh`, it is generated by the `R CMD BATCH` command. From the [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/BATCH.html), it suffices to add the name of the output file as last argument.

```
R CMD BATCH test.R /path/to/target/dir/test.Rout
```

Note that, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969145/why-or-when-is-rscript-or-littler-better-than-r-cmd-batch), you might want to consider `Rscript`. In that case, you can either redirect the `Rscript` output with `>`

```
Rscript test.R > /path/to/target/dir/test.Rout
```

in which case the file is written by Bash, or or use the `--output` option of sbatch in which case the output file is written by Slurm:

```
#SBATCH --output=/path/to/target/dir/test.Rout
Rscript test.R
```

but it will contain the full output of the job, not only the R part.

Comment: Is there a way to add a special character so that the name of the R script is used? Something similar to ```#SBATCH --output "out/slurm-%j.out"```, where the %j adds the number of the job to the file.